# Action Send Intent for Image not showing all share options

Tags: android

For some reason, when I try the following action send intent, it directly goes into the message page and attaches  the picture, instead of first displaying options such as Email, Messaging...

```
            File pic =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pictures.jpg");
            Uri pngUri = Uri.fromFile(pic);
            Intent picMessageIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
            picMessageIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            picMessageIntent.setType("image/*");  
            picMessageIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngUri);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(picMessageIntent, "Send your picture using:"));
```

Comment: Is this happening in an emulator or on your own device?

Comment: It is in the android emulator. I don't want to actually send the attachment to anyone, but for my class project we are to click  on a button which should display messaging, email option. So that when the messaging button is clicked, it attaches the image saved from the camera take picture method to it.